# Consulta SQL con Asynctask pasando parametro

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

estoy realizando una clase que extiende de Asynctask para realizar una modificación en mi base de datos SQLite de Android, para realizar la consulta se le debe pasar un parametro al método de dicha consulta, pero no se como pasarselo a la clase Asynctask, tengo esto por ahora:

```
 public class AsyncTaskDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    updateShowMain0(/*Parametro articulo*/);
    return null;
}

public void updateShowMain0(String articulo){
    SQLiteDatabase db = Utility.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    /*ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("showMain", 0);
    Log.i("","Recibe la consulta");
    return db.update("articles",valores,"description = ?", new String[]{articulo});
*/
    db.execSQL("UPDATE articles SET showMain = 0 WHERE description = ?", new String[]{articulo});
    Log.i("","Recibe la consulta");

}


}
```

Quisiera que el doinbackground se ejecute al cambiar el estado de un checkbox, ¿alguien podria guiarme un poco?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu clase AsyncTaskDB hereda de AsyncTask. Como notaras hay 3 parámetros que tienes como Void. Ese parámetro es el que tienes que cambiar si decides pasar algún dato al momento de ejecutar la tareas asincronica.

Por ejemplo, si quieres pasar un entero, necesitarías algo así:

```
public class AsyncTaskDB extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    //Recuerda que params es un arreglo
    updateShowMain0(params[0]);
    return null;
}
```